# Installing Discourse in Multiple Containers

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, forum, discourse

I'm currently working on setting up Discourse in EC2 and I'm interested in deploying it in a multi-container environment for scalability and flexibility.

I'm looking for detailed steps and best practices on how to properly install Discourse in a multi-container setup. Are there specific configuration files to modify, dependencies to be aware of, or Docker Compose configurations that need to be set up?

Any advice or instructions on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I was expecting that Discourse would be successfully deployed in a multi-container setup, allowing for scalability and flexibility in my project. I anticipated that the web and data containers would communicate seamlessly and that I would be able to access the Discourse instance through the specified port.